# Retrieve data from database when class created

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, oncreate

I have a fragment, when my Fragment starts I need to query my firebase realtime database. I am adding the database connection code directly when the onCreate method is run, I still get null when printing toast.

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View r = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friends, container, false);


        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        String userEmail = user.getEmail();

        DatabaseReference userDetails = db.getReference("users").child(userEmail);

        userDetails.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                myUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                postCount = myUser.getTotalPosts();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });



        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "jjjjj " + postCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

So what I did was I tried wrapping all the database connection and retrieve code in a static block because this should run first when the class is created

```
static{
 // everything in here from above code excluding the toast
}
```

I then tried printing **postCount** again inside of `onCreateView()` but still get the same outcome where postCount is null

How do I overcome this?

thanks

P.S I am sure that the node I am listening on exists in the database

Comment: Obviously you should use this value when is set. Obviously it's set inside ondatachange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply because `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` is working on another off UI thread(background thread) and your `Toast.makeText(...)` is working on UI thread.

Thus the execution of `Toast.makeText(..)` takes place even before the value of postCount gets updated. Thus in the `Toast.makeText()` you get the default value of postCount.

To remove this you can write

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "jjjjj " + postCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

in your onDataChange method.

eg:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
myUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
postCount = myUser.getTotalPosts();
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "jjjjj " + postCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```